# Using Ruby ask for value, store value in variable (x), read input file line by line, replace y with x, output file

Tags: ruby

I'm pretty new to scripting in general so I'm still learning a lot in my quest to learn ruby.

I'm not sure how clear my title is so I'll show you what I've started with.

```
puts "Enter the hostname in the format [SID-Profile] -->"
var1 = gets

puts "Enter the IP address and Mask in the format [1.2.3.4 255.255.255.0] -->"
var2 = gets
```

This is where my efforts fall apart and I'm starting to wonder if I've even approached the problem in a very practical way.

I would like to ask a series of questions, hold the answers to the questions in variables, then import a file, read it line by line finding @HOSTNAME in the file and replacing it with the value being held in var1.  Once the entire file has been searched and all instances of @HOSTNAME have been replace with var1, start again for var2.  This seemed like it would be quick when I first thought of it, but I'm stuck.

Any ideas?  If there are other approaches I'd love to hear those too.

Comment: Unrelated to your initial problem but you probably want to do `var1 = gets.chomp` because your `gets` input includes the ending Line Return when the user enters the info and then hits the `Enter` or `Return`  key. Just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: What part of your code is specifically giving you a problem?  It sounds like you know what you want to do, so what is preventing you from doing it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a way to do a replace in a file using ruby, but you can cheat a little.

I'd do both substitutions at the same time, so that you don't have to read the file twice. 
Try this

```
data = IO.readlines("filename")
puts "Enter Hostname"
hostname = gets.chomp
puts "Enter IP"
ip = gets.chomp
data.each do |line|
  line.gsub("@HOSTNAME",hostname)
  line.gsub!("@IPADDRESS",ip)
  puts line
end
```

This will read the file and print it to the screen, so that you can see and verify the output.

You can then direct the output of the script to a new file, and finally move the new file into the place of the old one.

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you!  I've already built on it a bit to give me an output file.  Fun!  :)

Comment: Lilly, if Adam has successfully helped you consider marking this as an answer so future visitors of this question will know it was answered.